# Creating a GIT project from specific commit of another GIT project

Tags: git, github

My team has created a gradel based spring GIT project with a lot of configuration. I was wondering if I can save my effort in creating new project require same configuration.

So I was planning to checkout some old commit of existing project, suppose C6. And create a new project from here.

A possible to do this may be;

1. Checkout C6
2. Create a new GIT repository.
3. Manually copy all the contents from old repository and paste to new repository
4. change the remote of new repository
5. Push the changes of new repository

But I am not sure whether it is a right approach and gonna work

Please suggest me a correct way to achieve it.

Comment: Is Forking what you are looking to do? https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo

Comment: I thought we can form branch only. Can we fork a repo from a particular commit?

Comment: @perisufi its interesting. But it doesn't let me fork from particular commit. It also doesn't let me choose the project name or existing repo. So not helpful for me. But really a good option.

Comment: Yeah, understandable. I would definitely go with Jean's answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clone the repository and reset master to C6

```
$ git reset --hard C6
```

Remove unwanted branches:

```
$ git branch -D branch_name
```

There will be a lot of dangling commits. Check them with:

```
$ git fsck --no-reflogs
```

and run these commands to remove dangling commits:

```
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all
$ git gc --prune=now
```

And remember to delete remote `origin`, or you will be
able to push/pull to/from the other repository
(considering the code base will not receive the same
updates):

```
$ git remote remove origin
```

Comment: +1 It seems promising. lemme try and update with my experience. thanks.

Comment: then I'll need to add the origin of new repository on github?

Comment: If the new repository is a different project: Clone the repository with the existing sources. Do the "master reallocation" of the answer. Remove current origin of the local repository. If it does not exist, create a repository for the new project on Github. Add the new origin as the Github repository.